Copy Sheet From Closed Workbook Into Existing Sheet (Overwrite) on another Workbook
I've tried some VBA codes in here but always end up with a code that create a new sheet on destination workbook.
What I want is to copy a sheet from closed workbook into existing sheet on an open workbook (overwrite).
Example:

"Sheet1" from closed workbook "Book1"
Copied to opened workbook "Book2" existing sheet named "Sheet2" without creating a new sheet.

Thanks
Sub COPYSHEET()

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Downloads\Book1.xlsx")

wbSource.Sheets(1).Copy before:=wbTarget.Sheets(1)
wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub


wbSource.Sheets(1).Copy before:=wbTarget.Sheets(1) copies/inserts the respective sheet before the first sheet of wbTarget.
To copy its content, please try the next way:
 With wbTarget.Sheets(1)
   .UsedRange.Clear
   wbSource.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy .Range("A1")
   .UsedRange.EntireColumn.autofit
 End With


Alright, Looks like your code solve my problem. Thank you.

Replace Sheet With Sheet From Closed Workbook
Usage
Sub ReplaceSheetFromClosedWorkbookTEST()
    ReplaceSheetFromClosedWorkbook _
        "C:\Users\user1\Downloads\Book1.xlsx", 1, "Sheet2", False
End Sub

The Method
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In the workbook containing this code ('ThisWorkbook'),
'               replaces a sheet ('DestinationSheetID')
'               with a sheet ('SourceSheetID') located in a closed workbook
'               ('SourceFiloPath'). Optionally ('SaveDestinationWorkbook'),
'               saves the destination workbook ('ThisWorkbook').
' Remarks:      The new sheet should be located at the same tab position
'               and should have the exact names as the old one.
'               Keep in mind that the sheets mustn't be hidden or protected.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ReplaceSheetFromClosedWorkbook( _
        SourceFiloPath As String, _
        SourceSheetID As Variant, _
        DestinationSheetID As Variant, _
        Optional SaveDestinationWorkbook As Boolean = False)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Replace Sheet With Sheet From Closed Workbook"
    Dim MsgString As String, WasSuccess As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFiloPath)
    Dim ssh As Object: Set ssh = swb.Sheets(SourceSheetID)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dosh As Object: Set dosh = dwb.Sheets(DestinationSheetID) ' old
    Dim dName As String: dName = dosh.Name ' if index was passed
    Dim dCodeName As String: dCodeName = dosh.CodeName
    
    ' Copy the (old) sheet.
    ssh.Copy Before:=dosh
    
    ' Close the source workbook.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Reference the new sheet.
    Dim dnsh As Object: Set dnsh = dosh.Previous ' new
    
    ' Delete the old sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
        dosh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Rename the new sheet.
    dnsh.Name = dName ' (tab) name
    dwb.VBProject.VBComponents(dnsh.CodeName).Name = dCodeName ' code name
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    If SaveDestinationWorkbook Then dwb.Save
    
    MsgString = "Replaced sheet """ & dName & """ in """ & dwb.FullName & """."
    
    WasSuccess = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in continuation
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' Inform.
        MsgBox MsgString, IIf(WasSuccess, vbInformation, vbCritical), PROC_TITLE
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgString = "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
         & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

